# Tkinter messagebox running twice

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm making an app which finds the time and Google description of the user's input, and if the input is invalid an error messagebox pops up. However, if I enter a valid input and run it, and then enter an invalid input and try to run it, the messagebox will open up again after I close it. Otherwise it works fine, and I'm not sure what the problem is. Any help would be great, thanks.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


root=tk.Tk()
root.title('Time app')

p_names=['London, Europe','Paris, Europe','Stockholm, Europe','Tokyo, Asia','Arizona, US','Pacific, US','Samoa, Pacific','Galapagos, Pacific','General, Mexico','Mauritius, Indian','Johannesburg, Africa','Barbados, America','Detroit, America','Addis Ababa, Africa','El Salvador, America','Bangkok, Asia']

def place_names():
    p_names.sort()
    li=''
    for pl in p_names:
        li+=pl
        li+='\n'
    return li+'\n'+'+ more'


def value():
    global a
    a = entry_1.get()
    try:
        a.index(',')
        if a.index(' ')<a.index(','):
            a=a.replace(' ','_')
    except:
        a=a
    
    return a


def times():

    try:
        b = a.index(',')
        c = a[b + 2:] + '/' + a[:b]
    
        if c in pytz.all_timezones:
            home = pytz.timezone(c)
            local_time = datetime.now(home)
            current_time = local_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    
            d= a
    
            try:
                e=d.index('_')
                if e<d.index(','):
                    d=d.replace('_',' ')
            except:
                d=a
    
            place_lbl = Label(root, text=d, bg='grey',width=15, font=('bold', 25))
            place_lbl.place(relx=0.33, rely=0.45)
    
            time_lbl = Label(root, text=current_time, bg='grey', font=('bold', 30))
            time_lbl.place(relx=0.41, rely=0.6)
            time_lbl.after(1000,times)
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Error',"Cannot find '{}'. Please enter in form city, continent (e.g. Arizona, US) or try another location.".format(a))
    except:
        messagebox.showerror('Error',"I Cannot find '{}'. Please enter in form city, continent (e.g. Arizona, US) or try another location.".format(a))
    
    return


def scraped():

    try:
        b = a.index(',')
        c = a[b + 2:] + '/' + a[:b]
    
        if c in pytz.all_timezones:
            PATH = '/Users/BenMcNally/Desktop/chromedriver'
            option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            option.add_argument('headless')
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=option)
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            driver.get('https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhj7PUqL_sAhXcURUIHZfmA4oQPAgI')
    
            try:
                search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
                search.send_keys(a)
                search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    
                desc = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="kp-wp-tab-overview"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]')))
    
                side_info_lbl.config(text=desc.text)
            except:
                side_info_lbl.update_idletasks()
                side_info_lbl.config(text='No description available')
    
    
            driver.quit()
    except:
        return


canvas=tk.Canvas(root,height=400,width=700,bg='grey')
canvas.grid()

header_lbl=Label(root,text='Enter a location: ',bg='grey',fg='black',font=('bold',25))
header_lbl.place(relx=0.38,rely=0.1)

entry_1=Entry(root)
entry_1.place(relx=0.37,rely=0.2)

search_btn = Button(root,text='Search',command=lambda:[value(),times(),entry_1.delete(0, 
END),scraped()])
search_btn.place(relx=0.47,rely=0.3)

show_lbl=Label(root,text='Locations',bg='grey',fg='black',font=('bold',20))
show_lbl.place(relx=0.12,rely=0.1)

side_list_lbl=Label(root,text=place_names(),bg='grey',fg='black')
side_list_lbl.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.2)

side_info_lbl = Label(root, text='', wraplength=200, bg='grey', 
fg='black',height=20,width=22)
side_info_lbl.place(relx=0.68, rely=0.1)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you called `.after` firstly.And when you enter a incorrect area, Both of them will raise exception.

So the solution is to stop `.after` method(use `.after_cancel()`) each time you pressed the button:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


root=tk.Tk()
root.title('Time app')

p_names=['London, Europe','Paris, Europe','Stockholm, Europe','Tokyo, Asia','Arizona, US','Pacific, US','Samoa, Pacific','Galapagos, Pacific','General, Mexico','Mauritius, Indian','Johannesburg, Africa','Barbados, America','Detroit, America','Addis Ababa, Africa','El Salvador, America','Bangkok, Asia']

def place_names():
    p_names.sort()
    li=''
    for pl in p_names:
        li+=pl
        li+='\n'
    return li+'\n'+'+ more'


def value():
    global a
    if root.get_time: # if you have run it. root.get_time wouldn't be None
        root.after_cancel(root.get_time) # cancel it
    a = entry_1.get()
    if root.get_time:
        root.after_cancel(root.get_time)
    try:
        a.index(',')
        if a.index(' ')<a.index(','):
            a=a.replace(' ','_')
    except:
        a=a
    return a


def times():
    try:
        b = a.index(',')
        c = a[b + 2:] + '/' + a[:b]

        if c in pytz.all_timezones:
            home = pytz.timezone(c)
            local_time = datetime.now(home)
            current_time = local_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

            d= a

            try:
                e=d.index('_')
                if e<d.index(','):
                    d=d.replace('_',' ')
            except:
                d=a

            place_lbl = Label(root, text=d, bg='grey',width=15, font=('bold', 25))
            place_lbl.place(relx=0.33, rely=0.45)

            time_lbl = Label(root, text=current_time, bg='grey', font=('bold', 30))
            time_lbl.place(relx=0.41, rely=0.6)
            root.get_time = root.after(1000, times)
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Error',"Cannot find '{}'. Please enter in form city, continent (e.g. Arizona, US) or try another location.".format(a))
    except:
        messagebox.showerror('Error',"I Cannot find '{}'. Please enter in form city, continent (e.g. Arizona, US) or try another location.".format(a))

    return


def scraped():
    try:
        b = a.index(',')
        c = a[b + 2:] + '/' + a[:b]

        if c in pytz.all_timezones:
            PATH = '/Users/BenMcNally/Desktop/chromedriver'
            option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            option.add_argument('headless')
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=option)
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            driver.get('https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhj7PUqL_sAhXcURUIHZfmA4oQPAgI')

            try:
                search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
                search.send_keys(a)
                search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

                desc = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="kp-wp-tab-overview"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]')))

                side_info_lbl.config(text=desc.text)
            except:
                side_info_lbl.update_idletasks()
                side_info_lbl.config(text='No description available')


            driver.quit()
    except:
        return


canvas=tk.Canvas(root,height=400,width=700,bg='grey')
canvas.grid()

header_lbl=Label(root,text='Enter a location: ',bg='grey',fg='black',font=('bold',25))
header_lbl.place(relx=0.38,rely=0.1)

entry_1=Entry(root)
entry_1.place(relx=0.37,rely=0.2)

root.get_time = None # init value
search_btn = Button(root,text='Search',command=lambda: [value(),times(),entry_1.delete(0, END),scraped()])
search_btn.place(relx=0.47,rely=0.3)

show_lbl=Label(root,text='Locations',bg='grey',fg='black',font=('bold',20))
show_lbl.place(relx=0.12,rely=0.1)

side_list_lbl=Label(root,text=place_names(),bg='grey',fg='black')
side_list_lbl.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.2)

side_info_lbl = Label(root, text='', wraplength=200, bg='grey',
fg='black',height=20,width=22)
side_info_lbl.place(relx=0.68, rely=0.1)


root.mainloop()
```